# Avoid public internet access for single node elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch - 7.9.1

As per my understanding, adding `discovery.type=single-node` will make sure no other nodes can join the cluster. What changes needed to make sure Elasticsearch is no accessible via public internet.

Useful part of the `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
  container_name: elasticsearch
  environment:
    - node.name=elasticsearch
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
  volumes:
    - data:/usr/share/es/data
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running it in Docker container, so changing Elasticsearch setting is not enough. You need to make sure container itself is not publishing Elasticsearch to public IP address.
You have to change published ports in docker-compose.yml file to this

```
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:9200:9200"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything, as by default `network.host` binds to loopback address only as mentioned in [its official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/network.host.html)

If you put `network.hots: 0.0.0.0` than it will bind to all network interfaces and in absence of proper security group(AWS) or firewall, it might be accessible publicly. refer [official doc of common-settings of network.host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings)

Comment: when I checked into the container, I see - `network.host: 0.0.0.0` which is strange.

Comment: @Dev any luck ?